# How to color console.trace in node.js?

Tags: node.js, stack-trace, console.log

For making output colorful in node.js I am using [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk). I wonder, if there are any ways to color console.trace() output?

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tracer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Node.js, method `console.trace` compiles the data and then forwards it into `console.error`.

Below is an example of using module [manakin](https://github.com/vitaly-t/manakin):

```
require('manakin').global;    
console.trace(); // prints the trace using red
```

Since the library assigns red color by default to method `console.error`, the trace will also appear red, though you can change it:

```
var con = require('manakin').global;
con.error.color = 35; // use magenta for errors;
console.trace(); // prints the trace using magenta
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can use **%c** formatter in `console.log` or `console.trace`

e.g

```
console.log('%c This is test...','font-size:18px; background:green;');

console.trace('%c This is test...','font-size:18px; background:green;');
```

This works perfectly in browser, but I have not tested it `node.js` scripts.

You may give it a try.

Comment: The question was specifically about Node.js, and your code does not work in Node.js.